# Beamer - change position of a bullet

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets

After writing

```
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{itemize}\itemsep=1em
    
\item Motivace
  
\end{itemize}
\end{LARGE}

\end{frame}
```

I got this in my presentaion:

[image]

But is there any way to it looks like this?

[image]

I don't like the bullet being this down and I couldn't find how to fix it. Thank you.

Full code:

```
\usepackage[verbose,absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.47\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.53\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
    \parbox{.53\paperwidth}{\inserttitle}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}


\author{XX YY}
\title[Název upřesním pak]{Název upřesním pak}
\date{yx.\,července 2020}
%
\begin{document}
%


\begin{frame}
   \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
    
\begin{LARGE}
    
\begin{itemize}
    \item Motivace
    \item Další zajímavý věci
    \item Závěr
\end{itemize}

\end{LARGE}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{}
    Děkuji za pozornost.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to improve the vertical position of the ball symbol with respect to the `LARGE` text, you could redefine the `ball` itemize styleas follows

I have copied the original definition from the file `beamerbaseaustemplates.sty` and changed the value of `\raise` from its original value of `0.2pt` to `3pt`. Apart from that, I have also replaced the inexistent `LARGE` environment from your original example with the `\LARGE` switch.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{myball}{\raise3pt\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{items}[myball]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\LARGE
\begin{itemize}
  \item Motivace
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Side note: From the text in your MWE, I guess, this specific slide is supposed to be an outline/table of contents of your presentation. Why don't you use sections and the `\tableofcontents` command to automatically create such a slide?

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's part of table of contents. And to answer your question, I don't know. This was a part of some pattern for presentaion (given by my school) so I used it. I am new to latex so ...